# How do you rename an attachment and save it in outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-office

I want to rename an attachment in outlook using the below code. But I dont know how to do it.

Ideally it would be good if it renamed the file attachment with the person who sent it and the current date. So if it was sent by jill@gmail.com it would rename the file as jill@gmail.com230719

See below code

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String

    ' Get the path to your My Documents folder
    strFolderpath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
    Set objOL = Application

    ' Get the collection of selected objects.
    Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

' The attachment folder needs to exist
' You can change this to another folder name of your choice

    ' Set the Attachment folder.
    strFolderpath = strFolderpath & "\OLAttachments\"

    ' Check each selected item for attachments.
    For Each objMsg In objSelection

    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count

    If lngCount > 0 Then

    ' Use a count down loop for removing items
    ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
    ' confused and only every other item is removed.

    For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

    ' Get the file name.
    strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName

    ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
    strFile = strFolderpath & strFile

    ' Save the attachment as a file.
    objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile

    Next i
    End If

    Next

ExitSub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This line is Assigning the Name in the Code:**

```
strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
```

**Change it to:**

```
strFile = Split(objMsg.SenderEmailAddress, "@")(0) & Format(objMsg.ReceivedTime, "ddmmyyyy") & "." & Split(Right(objAttachments.Item(i).FileName,8), ".")(1)
```

---

`objMsg.SenderEmailAddress` will give you the Email Address of Sender

`objMsg.ReceivedTime` will give you the time

Comment: It is working like its supposed to. Only small thing is its not recognizing the file extension since if it saves it has jill@gmail.com230719 it sees the extension as .com230719. Is there a way to just save the first five letters then the date? as in jill@230719

Comment: Use the Updated Answer :)

Comment: Works like a dream. Thanks. Im fairly new to vba programming so objects and file paths are unfamiliar

Comment: @don ...Happy to Help. Accept the Answer :)

Comment: One last thing I only see now. It is possible there can be two files with the same name. How do I avoid this program from overwriting an already saved file? there can be two files on the same day with the same sender( jill in this case) but the files are different. I tried

    strFile = strFolderpath & j & strFile

with the j being a variable but it loses its effectiveness to search for all the files sent by jill when you search